# Android: Show other than first tab in tabwidget on class call via intent

Tags: android, tabs, android-intent, tabwidget

I am trying to open a class with a tabwidget via intent. But depending on where the class is called from, I am trying to get it to start with a different active tab.

E.g. I have three tabs: Houses, Cars, Boats in a class called ViewPossesions.
Depending on where I call the ViewPossesions from, I would like a different tab to show initially. E.g. when called from Class A, I want the standard first tab open, but when calling from Class B, I want the "Cars" tab to be active.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to explain :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do in this case is add a parameter to the Intent, and extract it when your activity gets called. To embed extra data in an Intent, you can use putExtra (1) and its many variations, and then get your data using getExtras().

This parameter would indicate to the activity what is the tab that should be displayed.

(1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
(2)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()

Comment: Thanks for your help. I also just stumbled upon this (http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2011/04/returning-to-specific-tab-from-another.html) which suggests the same solution.